# Changing the x lables using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, x-axis, xlabs

I have this data and plot it using a bar plot. I want to change the x labels to make it simple,

```
data_bayes <- read.table(text="
Estimation,Cell types,Total
No rank,Cell type 0 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 1 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 2 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 3 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 4 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 5 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 6 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 7 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 8 ,3468
No rank,Cell type 9 ,3468
Best three rank,Cell type 0 ,3
Best three rank,Cell type 1 ,3419
Best three rank,Cell type 2 ,130
Best three rank,Cell type 3 ,0
Best three rank,Cell type 4 ,538
Best three rank,Cell type 5 ,63
Best three rank,Cell type 6 ,3417
Best three rank,Cell type 7 ,2296
Best three rank,Cell type 8 ,536
Best three rank,Cell type 9 ,2
", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

I use this code to get the plot

```
ggplot(data_bayes, aes(x=Cell.types, y=Total, fill=Estimation)) + scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Best three rank", "No rank"), 
                   values=c("green", "red")) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + scale_x_discrete(
"Cell types",
labels = c(
  "Cell type 0" = "0",
  "Cell type 1" = "1",
  "Cell type 2" = "2",
  "Cell type 3" = "3",
  "Cell type 4" = "4",
  "Cell type 5" = "5",
  "Cell type 6" = "6",
  "Cell type 7" = "7",
  "Cell type 8" = "8",
  "Cell type 9" = "9"
)
)
```

It will result this plot
[image]

I have used the argument scale_x_discrete to change the labels from cell type 0 to 0, etc. However, it does not change and remains same. Why is that the case? How to fix it?

Comment: Your data has a blank space (" ") after each cell type number, but your labels do not. If you remove the blank space in the data (or add it in the labels), this approach will work fine

Comment: @JacobRothschild Nice catch. I do not realise that. It works as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this could be:

1. We create a label column before we plot `label_cell.types`
2. Then factor it and plot

```
library(tidyverse)

data_bayes %>% 
  mutate(label_cell.types = parse_number(Cell.types)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(label_cell.types), y=Total, fill=Estimation)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Best three rank", "No rank"), values=c("green", "red")) +
  labs(x = "Cell types")+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]